# Defining a property of a variable that includes another function (sign)

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, probability-or-statistics, syntax, downvalues

I have a function that has a lot of sign functions that depend on a variable $\sigma$ and I know the property that $\sigma=1$ with probability $m$ and $-1$ with probability $1-m$. For example we can consider

```
s = Sign[1 + .3 σ] + Sign[.1 σ]
```

I want to use the property that the average over all possibilities of $\sigma$ implies
$$\langle\mathrm{sgn} (a+b\cdot \sigma)\rangle _\sigma =m\cdot \mathrm{sgn} (a+b) +(1-m) \cdot\mathrm{sgn} (a-b)$$

so that in this case $\langle s\rangle$ will be simplified to $2m$. I tried to use TagSet or ReplaceAll but I don't know how to do it properly. My intuition was to try something like

```
σ /: Sign[a + b σ] = m Sign[a + b] + (1 - m) Sign[a - b]
```

and apply this property whenever I want to evaluate the average, but I can't do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use the built-in distributions in Mathematica. For example:

```
σ = TransformedDistribution[2 x - 1, Distributed[x,  BinomialDistribution[1, m]];
```

Then, you can do things like:

```
Expectation[Sign[a + b x], Distributed[x, σ]]
```

> (1 - m) Sign[a - b] + m Sign[a + b]

which recovers your expected average. For your first example:

```
Expectation[Sign[1 + .3 x] + Sign[.1 x], Distributed[x, σ]]
```

> 2 m

Comment: What an elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

**Using *`UpValues`* the '*straightforward*' way:**

Evaluating `Sign[a_+b_ σ]^=m Sign[(a+b)]+(1-m)Sign[(a-b)]` produces an `UpSet::write` error message, informing the user that *`"Tag Plus in Sign[a+b\ σ] is Protected."`*. This makes sense, as *`UpSet`* associates the *rhs* with the head of the expression in *`Sign`*, which is *`Plus`*; *`Plus`* is a built-in *`Protected`* symbol, hence the error.

**Using *`UpValues`* more productively:**

The failure, to produce an acceptable definition, points towards a way around the problem; replacing the head of the expression in *`Sign`* with something else, rather than *`Plus`*, seems to work.

Evaluating

```
Sign[wrapper[a_ + b_ σ]] ^= m Sign[(a + b)] + (1 - m) Sign[(a - b)]
```

doesn't produce any error messages and *eg* `Sign[wrapper[A+B σ]]` evaluates-*as expected*-to `(1 - m) Sign[A - B] + m Sign[A + B]`.

**A solution using *`UpValues`***:

The question needs a way to tackle expressions like `s` (see question). The following definition seems to do the trick:

```
Sign[wrapper[a_, b_]] ^:= Plus @@ Plus @@ ({m, 1 - m} Sign[{a + b, a - b}])
```

Evaluating the example for `s`, evaluates to

```
Sign[wrapper[{1, 0}, {0.3, 0.1}]]
```

> ```
>  2m
> ```

**An alternative route:**

Using a `wrapper` to make *`UpValues`* work for this problem seems a bit contrived. A more natural way is to use a user-defined `sign` function that operates of expressions like `s` (see question).

```
ClearAll[s]
Options[s] = {Probabilities -> m};
sign[a_List, b_List, OptionsPattern[]] := With[{prob = OptionValue[Probabilities]},
  Plus @@ Plus @@ ({prob, 1 - prob} Sign[{a + b, a - b}])
 ]
```

Again, seeing as there is little change in the core functionality of the code used, the example for `s` ie `sign[{1, 0}, {0.3, 0.1}]` evaluates to

> ```
> 2m
> ```